# Finding info about immigrant relative in USA

Tags: united-states, immigration

Is there a site (preferably free) for accessing info about people who migrated to USA?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! This question is not a good fit for our site.  See https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask in our [help].  Your question encourges a list of answers where every answer is equally valid. You can discover new resources for finding information about people who emigrated to the USA by reading the questions on the site about immigrants.  Search for the tag  [tag:immigration].  To learn more about the site, see our companion [meta]. For example, https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2057/1006 discusses quesrtions from people asking for free resources.

Comment: @JanMurphy Thanks for the clarification. I will read the links you provided.

Comment: You can edit your question by using the edit link under your question, if you want to ask a specific question about a problem you're having finding immigration records.  Knowing the time period and the possible departure port will help narrow things down so we can write a better answer.  Search the site first to see if any of our existing questions help. The FamilySearch Wiki article https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/United_States_Emigration_and_Immigration might be of interest.

Comment: @JanMurphy you're totally right about my question. I just thought it would be nice if we had all those sites in one question for reference.

Comment: There's no point in us trying to reinvent the wheel. https://cyndislist.com/immigration

Answer (score 3):

If they have arrived in the U.S. several decades ago, then I suggest you start with LDS's [FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/) site. (As of this writing, it's free, but requires registration and login.)

For example, I can search for my  second great aunt like this:

`https://www.familysearch.org/search/record/results?q.givenName=Ruchlia%20&q.surname=Wulis`

and see right away that she arrived at Ellis Island in 1909 on the *Lusitania*.

Their collection is not limited to Ellis Island, but also has passenger lists from Philadelphia and several other widely used ports of entry; some Canadian border crossings; censuses (1950 is the latest available); naturalization papers, and many other databases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can visit [EllisIslandPassengerSearch](https://heritage.statueofliberty.org/passenger) and search. Don't forget to use the **Wizard** and the **filter**.

Extremely helpful and completely free.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are answering your own question? :)

Comment: @jadepx I think many people are not aware of this site, so I made the post. Also, I want to find more similar sites.